# Are POSIX message queues machine specific?

Tags: posix, message-queue, cross-server

I am looking for asynchronous communication on Linux between 2 processes running on different machines. POSIX message queues seem a good solution for async part of it. It however seems like they are machine specific. In other words, if I create a message queue one machine A, then it is visible only on machine A. So IPC between 2 processes running on 2 different machines cannot really use POSIX message queues. Is my understanding correct? Are POSIX message queues specific to machines?

Comment: Yes, they're machine specific, just like all other IPC methods. The only inter-machine communications is network sockets.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the response!